# Finding minimum of a symbolic function

Tags: mathematical-optimization, symbolic

Why does *Mathematica* fails to find the minima of the two variable function with real coefficients. The function and my attempt is given below.

Input:

```
 FindMinimum[
     a (x - vh^2/2)^2 + b (y - vs^2/2)^2,  {a, b, vh, vs} \[Element] 
      Real]
```

output:

```
FindMinimum::ivar`
```

Note that I want a minimum w.r.t to both x and y.
Any suggestions, please.

How if the a,b ->  \sqrt[a], \sqrt[b] ?

Comment: You didn't mentioned you get the `FindMinimum::ivar` error. The community [expects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): 
✅: A clear description of an on-topic problem or goal.
✅: A minimal working *Wolfram Language* code example, formatted, easy to *copy&paste*.
❌. An example of what you expect as output.
❌. Some proof of minimal *Mathematica* knowledge. 
❌. Minimum due diligence: Share how you have searched the site and documentation, your attempts and reasons to believe an answer exists.

Comment: Maybe `Minimize[
 a (x - vh^2/2)^2 + b (y - vs^2/2)^2 + 
  c (x - vh^2/2) (y - vs^2/2), {x, y}]`

Comment: We only need to consider `a*u^2+b*v^2+c*u*v`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by Ulrich Neumann (+1), the correct function for what you want is [`Minimize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minimize.html), not [`FindMinimum`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMinimum.html), see below why your attempt didn't work.

## Solution

You can use [`Minimize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minimize.html), but unless you constraint the values for your variables (In this case using [`Assuming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html)), you get a very complicated expression. Here I show you the simplest case for positive parameters and $4 a b >c^2$:

```
Assuming[
    And[
        {a, b, c, vh, vs} ∈ PositiveReals, 
        4 a b > c^2
    ],
    FullSimplify@Minimize[
        a (x - vh^2/2)^2 + b (y - vs^2/2)^2 +  c (x - vh^2/2) (y - vs^2/2)
        , {x, y}
    ]
]
```

[image]

---

## Your mistake

Your code didn't work for many reasons:

- [`Real`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Real.html) is not the same as [`Reals`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reals.html).
- [`FindMinimum[ f[x], {x,xo} ]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMinimum.html) needs to evaluate `f[x]` to a number, but you have undefined parameters `{a, b, c, vh, vs}`
- Your syntax is not what `FindMinimum` expects

Comment: Nice answer! Do you know how mathematica find these minima?

Comment: I want to know the underlying method where mathematica us first or second order derivative or without it.

Comment: @SciJewel No, we don't know in detail how is done, the documentation doesn't say and `TracePrint` doesn't reveal anything useful. In general Wolfram doesn't disclose implementation details. Presumably, it does something similar you would do, solving for derivative roots.

Comment: Do you also find another minimum as I do for 4 a b == c^2. In this case I find different terms for x and y. If I change the order of the variable that is, Minimize[f{x,y}, {x,y}] and  Minimize[f{x,y}, {y,x}], the minima are different and interchanged.

Comment: When I use \sqrt[a], \sqrt[b] instead of a, b, it cannot find find the solutions. I even changed the assumption to  \sqrt[a], \sqrt[b]  as  Positive reals. Still, doesn't work. could you please check it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`FindMinimum` expects numerical input, try  `Minimize`:

```
mini=Minimize[a (x - vh^2/2)^2 + b (y - vs^2/2)^2 + c (x - vh^2/2) (y - vs^2/2), {x, y}]

Simplify[mini, a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0]
```

[image]

gives minimum -Infinity if 4 a b <c^2 and several other solutions.

Comment: It cannot be infinity.